# Как передать массив в хранимую процедуру?

Tags: mysql

Следующая процедура реализует поиск значений из таблицы `posts`, используя связь **many to many** с таблицей `tags` через таблицу `posts_tags`:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `search_posts_by_tags_and` (IN `tags_query` TINYTEXT, IN `count` TINYINT)
BEGIN

SET @sql = CONCAT(
'SELECT * FROM `posts` AS `P`
LEFT JOIN `posts_tags` AS R ON `P`.`id` = `R`.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN `tags` AS `T` ON `T`.`id` = `R`.`tag_id`
WHERE `T`.`tag` IN (\'',              # Принимаем строку вида "javascript&jquery&dojo"
REPLACE(`tags_query`,'&','\',\''),    # и приводим её к виду "javascript','jquery','dojo"
'\')
GROUP BY `P`.`id`
HAVING COUNT(`P`.`id`) = ', `count`
);

PREPARE `search_posts_by_tags_and` FROM @sql;
EXECUTE `search_posts_by_tags_and`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `search_posts_by_tags_and`;

END //
```

В результате, процедура выполняет следующий запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` AS `P`
LEFT JOIN `posts_tags` AS `R` ON `P`.`id` = `R`.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN `tags` AS `T` ON `T`.`id` = `R`.`tag_id`
WHERE `T`.`tag` IN('javascript','jquery','dojo') # Принимаем список значений тегов
GROUP BY `P`.`id`
HAVING COUNT(`P`.`id`) = 3; # Принимаем количество переданных значений
```

Можно ли реализовать это более элегантно и передать данные процедуре в более *чистом* виде, не преобразуя их перед вызовом процедуры в строку и не прибегая к использованию `CONCAT()` в самой процедуре?

Comment: Хорошо бы в подобных вопросах указывать версии продуктов, которые вы используете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое что бросается в глаза: в хранимую процедуру запихнули избыточную и несвойственную ей логику, которая по-хорошему должна исполняться не на Data Layer, а на Application Layer.

Хранимая процедура – прекомпилируемый объект и в этом её прелесть, как с точки зрения скорости исполнения, так и в плане manageability. Использовать сложную, динамически-создаваемую строку в sp – означает выполнение предварительной подготовки параметров, поиска строк, конкатенации, сдвигов и проч. **средствами базы**. Это совершенно бесполезная работа так как процедура все равно будет заново компилироваться при каждом исполнении.

Например, намного легче и изящней создать тот же самый динамический запрос на любом высокоуровневом языке программирования и передать его в базу, чем мучаться с разбором параметров и склеиванием строк на стороне базы. При этом план выполнения будет одинаково медленным.

Если все же есть острая необходимость поехать из Москвы в Воронеж через Санкт-Петербург, то помогут либо динамические [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), либо функция [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Вот пара тематических постов на папе:

- [Pass array to MySQL stored routine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149545/pass-array-to-mysql-stored-routine)
- [How to Pass a List of String in MySQL Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103058/how-to-pass-a-list-of-string-in-mysql-stored-procedure)
- [MYSQL - Stored Procedure Utilising Comma Separated String As Variable Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463001/mysql-stored-procedure-utilising-comma-separated-string-as-variable-input)